# Laravel - preventing the user from clicking back button

Tags: php, laravel

I know that there're plenty many similar articles but I would like to explain the difference in mine.

Laravel based project - an user forgets to save his/her project and a back up is stored in a database. When the user logs in then, a check for a back up existence is made, and if there's a backup role, a session is generated, which activates a modal, prompting the user to pick a choice - either continue working on the last saved project or on the back up one. No matter what the user choose, a redirect to the editor page is made, where the session variable and the back up role are cleaned. But then, if the user clicks the back button, the modal is displayed again.

The questions are:

1. The alternatives of preventing a back click are only the session, or?
2. The browser remembers exactly the session variables on already loaded pages, so if we create a session in the redirected view and the click the back button, the new session variable will not persist?

Comment: You can handle this kind of scenario by using middleware or db.

Comment: You can't **prevent** a click on the back button. What you can handle are the side effects. Pls bear in mind, that the browser does not store session variables, it only stores a session id either in a cookie or in the url. The server-side may not even be aware that the user clicked the back button because there may not be a page reload as a result of this click.

Comment: @Shadow yes, exactly. Page reload and page back acts differently. After the redirect to the editor page, if I redirect to it again and then go to the dashboard, there will be no problem but clicking back, activates the modal.

Comment: @DilipHirapara I though it, but the problem is that the whole editor is created only with the check of session, no middleware, so it's going to work with middleware?

Comment: That modal is probably triggered by js in the browser, so your question has not much to do with php or laravel.

Comment: @Shadow mm, in principle yes, it's activated from JavaScript, which is called from php in a blade template. You can image it this way - after login a check is made, and in the blade, the modal is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use session, when user submit the answer use

```
Session::put("checked", true):
```

and make a middleware and add it to the editor route.

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Session::get("checked"))
        {
            return redirect('errorPage');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Why to the editor route? The modal is displayed in the dashboard, the user submits the form with the "checked" session, it's redirect to the editor. Then if the user hits back to the dashboard, an if-check through the middleware for the session must be made and if there is such session variable - not displaying the modal. The question is, after clicking the back button, will the "checked" session variable but available?

Comment: you can't prevent the user from clicking on a button in the browser, but you can prevent the action in your website, after the user submit the answer the session variable will be available till the session ends and the user will not be able to submit that answer again.